# Is it possible to get old value from map after inserting new one?

Tags: java, hazelcast, consistency, distributed-caching, hazelcast-imap

I have hazelcast cluster, which consist of 4 nodes. Settings looks like this:

```
<hazelcast>
    ...
    <map name="default">
        <backup-count>1</backup-count>

        <async-backup-count>0</async-backup-count>

        <time-to-live-seconds>0</time-to-live-seconds>

        <eviction-policy>LRU</eviction-policy>

        <max-size policy="cluster_wide_map_size">5000</max-size>
    </map>
</hazelcast>
```

Most important part is **synchronous backup**.

I am using [hazelcast iMap](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IMap.html) like this:

```
IMap<String, Object> map = getClient().getMap("default");
map.putAsync("key1", "1").get(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

//
String firstGet = map.getAsync("key1").get(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
map.putAsync("key1", firstGet + "2").get(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

// 
String secondGet = map.getAsync("key1").get(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
map.putAsync("key1", secondGet + "3").get(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

// 
String thirdGet = map.getAsync("key1").get(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

I expect, that **thirdGet** is equal to **"123"**. But I get **"13"** very rarely. It seems, that my second update is lost in some cases. But I don't see any errors in logs.

It is important, that this error appears, when system has maximum number of requests.

I thought about cache eviction. But in that case, I would lost whole key. But I lost only second update of my item.

Also I know, that Hazelcast is an AP product. But I have synchronous replication.

Comment: Your code has race condition. That is why sometimes you miss updates

Comment: @Ivan how it possible? I mean, I have sequential code.

Comment: How do you process that `maximum number of requests`? By creating several threads/using thread pools?

Comment: @Ivan I have server threads. But I have a bug in case of sequential using map. Like, first thread gets, putAsync1, then there is a pause for a while (4 second, for example). Then second thread makes gets, puts.

Comment: What happens if one thread puts value 1 just before another thread executes `secondGet = ....`?

Comment: @Ivan I hope, that second thread gets value 1, and it works like this.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually a good example to understand async code :) as you have experienced async calls does not guarantee they will return as soon as they are submitted, so you can lose the order. What you currently doing is submitting an async operation, waiting for at most 1000ms for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result, if available. Some can return in a few ms, while others can't make it in 1000ms. You just get a Future object and wait and say you will wait only 1000ms for it to be finished.

You need to use sync operations (map.put, map.get etc.) to ensure they're completed as they return. The IMap backup setting you use is not related to this, it is to define creating backup replicas in async/sync mode. Please see: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.10.2/manual/html-single/index.html#backing-up-maps

Comment: ```.get(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)``` throws ```TimeoutException```, if result is still unavailable.

Comment: Yes, because you say "I want to wait 1000ms at max for this invocation to return". If you want to wait for the result then you'll need to wait without a timeout in case of async calls like this.